# c# conditionally continue according base class behaviour

Tags: c#, class, inheritance, instantiation, radix

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        // DoSomething
        // If something is not correct return null;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B() :base()
    {
        // Check if everything was fine in base class
    }
}
```

How to check here if base class returned null or it has done his job? Then according this, I want to stop being instantiated ?

Thanks.

Comment: If something doesn't works right there are errors so you should use try-catch statements

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using *factory method* instead of constructor:

```
public class A
{
    protected A()
    {
        ...
    }

    protected Boolean IsCorrect() {...}

    public static A Create() {
      result A = new A();

      if (!IsCorrect())     
        return null;
      else
        return result;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    protected B() :base()
    {
       ...        
    }

    public static B Create() { 
      result B = new B();

      if (!IsCorrect())     
        return null;
      else
        return result; 
    }
}
```

....

```
  B value = B.Create(); // instance of B or null
```

Answer (score 1):

Constructor cannot fail, thus it cannot return `null`.

You may either consider of using `try-catch` and `throw`, or making a flag in the `base class` which will be `true` or `false` based on your initialization, like this.

```
public class A
{
    public bool IsInitializationOk; //by default, this is false
    public A()
    {
        // DoSomething
        if(something is not correct)
            return;
        IsInitializationOk = true;
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public B() :base()
    {
        // Check if everything was fine in base class
        if (IsInitializationOk){
            //Do something.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to check here if base class returned null or it has done his job?

A constructor doesn't return anything. The purpose of a constructor is to bring your object to initialization state such that it is ready to be worked with.

The real question is *how should I signal any derived class if initialization failed in the base*, and that has many answers which depends on the context IMO.

If the `DoStuff` is mission critical and must work for this object hierarchy to work, then throwing an exception is the proper way to handle this, as you can't really work with the object.

If `DoStuff` is "nice to have", but not critical for working with the object, you can simply keep a protected `bool` signaling failure or success:

```
public class A
{
    protected bool wasSuccessfull;
    public A()
    {
        wasSuccessfull = DoStuff();
    }

    public bool DoStuff() => true;
}

public class B : A
{
    public B()
    {
        if (wasSuccessfull) 
            Console.WriteLine("yay");
    }
}
```

I usually try to avoid heavy lifting in the constructor of the object. If you have a long running operation do to, I usually like to document and expose an `Initialize` method. When I create a new object, I like it to be available as soon as possible to the caller, avoiding any potential long hang, such as connecting to a database for example.

Comment: If the `DoStuff` is only "nice-to-have" it should not go to the constructor IMO but to a method which might or might not be called appropriately.

Comment: Read my last paragraph, that's more or less what I said. I would do that as well if it were my decision. I'm just listing the possibilities here, as I'm not sure one if actually "better" than the other.

Comment: Indeed I did not read it correctly. +1 for the many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

A constructor does not return anything (except the constructed instance). Therefor you cannot check if it returns `null`. However you may throw an exception within the base-class constructor which indicates that something whrong happend. Having said this you should not need to check if your constructor returned any instance and assume that it does its job right as long as no exception was thrown.